# IPv6 zero compression

Tags: networking, ipv6

When using zero-compression on the following IPv6 address

```
2001:0DB8:0000:CD30:0000:0000:0000:0000/60
```

Why is this not correct:

```
2001:DB8::CD30::/60
```

... while this is:

```
2001:DB8:0:CD30::/60
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Zero compression can only be made once. The reason for this is, that the IPv6 address is not unique any more otherwise.

Take your example `2001:DB8::CD30::/60` will it expand to

```
2001:0DB8:0000:0000:0000:CD30:0000:0000/60
```

or

```
2001:0DB8:0000:0000:CD30:0000:0000:0000/60
```

or

```
2001:0DB8:0000:CD30:0000:0000:0000:0000/60
```

...?

If only one "::" is used, the result will always be unique as there is only one possible fixed number of zeros to be inserted.

Answer (score 1):

Because it is ambiguous.

The address `2001:DB8::CD30::` could be expanded in any of the following possibilities:

`2001:DB8:0:CD30:0:0:0:0`

`2001:DB8:0:0:CD30:0:0:0`

`2001:DB8:0:0:0:CD30:0:0`

`2001:DB8:0:0:0:0:CD30:0`

Comment: Why the downvote? This answer is objectively correct.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that `::` is used to shorten multiple zeros in the 16-bit address field.

In your example `2001:0DB8:0000:CD30:0000:0000:0000:0000/60`, it only has multiple 0s in the 16-bit field at the suffix, the `0000` in `2001:0DB8:0000:CD30:` is just one 16-bit field and you'd just use `0` to shorten it.

**More interesting question: How would you shorten this`2001:0000:0000:CD30:0000:0000:0000:0000/60`?**

It is defined in the [standard](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5952#section-2.2):

> In addition, Section 2.2 of [RFC4291] notes,
>
> ```
>   'The "::" can only appear once in an address.'
> ```

What it means that the address can be written as either:
`2001:0:0:CD30::/60` **OR** `2001::0:CD30:0:0:0:0/60`.

Both are valid, but I'd prefer the first representation since the purpose of zeroco mpression is to shorten the address where the first representation is shorter.